# Is there a way to get version of production model in mlflow?

Tags: python, mlflow

I use `mlflow 1.23.1` and when trying to load model via `models:/model_name/Production` I receive error described [here](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/5171#issuecomment-1027234578) with `405` code `Method not allowed`. Setting versions of `mlflow` and `python` the same on client and server didn't help. However, loading model with `models:/model_name/version` works fine. So I wonder if there is a way to deduce which version Production stage has?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the model version that is in the **Production** stage, you can filter for the model name with `client.search_model_versions()` and return the version if the stage is **Production**.

```py
from mlflow.tracking import MlflowClient
client = MlflowClient()

model_name = "model_name"
stage = "Production"

client = MlflowClient()
for mv in client.search_model_versions(f"name='{model_name}'"):
    if mv.current_stage == stage:
        print(mv.version)
```

But if you are trying to get the version of MLFlow that was logged with the model, you can either print the `MLModel` or `requirements.txt` artifact files. Or you can load it and then infer from its metadata. As mentioned loading, it throws an error for you so I suggest the former or just navigating to the run in the UI.

```py
model_uri = "models:/model_name/Production"

# print artifacts
print(mlflow.artifacts.load_text(model_uri + "/MLmodel"))
print(mlflow.artifacts.load_text(model_uri + "/requirements.txt"))

# load and print print version
model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_uri)
print(model.metadata.mlflow_version)
```

Comment: As of your second proposition, I mentioned that I can't use `mlflow.pyfunc.load_model("models:/model_name/Production")`, it gives error. As of first, I'll try it, thanks for suggestion

Comment: Oh I see. So you need to check the version of mlflow without loading the model? If this is a one off thing you can always just navigate to the run in the UI and look at the `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Updated answer with a way to check the req without using the UI

Comment: No, I don't need to check `mlflow` version, I know it, I need to know version of model which is in `Production` stage.
P.S. How can I tag your nickname? `@` doesn't work

Comment: Oh, then my first example should do the trick. As for the `@`, I am not sure. Might be because I had a space in it.